# Background-size is not affected by input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

I set the background-size to `100% 0%` for both buttons below, for I want to show the "radio" button when text is put into the inputs and all radio fields are checked. But the "Text" button is already shown without anything put into the input fields. But when I remove the radio fields it works, what is causing this issue?

```css
  button {
   color: #FFF;
   border: none;
   background-color: transparent;
   transition: all 1s;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 20px 50px;   
   background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 100%);
   background-position: 100% 100%;
   background-size: 100% 0%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
  :checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 25%;
 }

 :checked ~:checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 50%;
 }
 
 :checked ~:checked ~:checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 75%;
 }
 
 :checked ~:checked ~:checked ~:checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
:valid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 25%;
 }

 :valid ~:valid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 50%;
 }
 
 :valid ~:valid ~:valid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 75%;
 }
 
 :valid ~:valid ~:valid ~:valid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
 }

 div {
   padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
R1 <input type="radio" name="">
R2 <input type="radio" name="">
R3 <input type="radio" name="">
R4 <input type="radio" name="">
Name <input type="text" name="" required=required>
Last <input type="text" name="" required=required>
Address <input type="text" name="" required=required>
Age <input type="text" name="" required=required>
<div>
  <button>Radio</button>
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Changed the `:valid` to `:invalid` (and switched the percentages).
2. Used the `:not(:invalid)` selector for the `100% 100%` background.

```css
button {
   color: #FFF;
   border: none;
   background-color: transparent;
   transition: all 1s;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 20px 50px;   
   background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 100%);
   background-position: 100% 100%;
   background-size: 100% 0%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
  :checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 25%;
 }

 :checked ~:checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 50%;
 }
 
 :checked ~:checked ~:checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 75%;
 }
 
 :checked ~:checked ~:checked ~:checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
:not(:invalid) ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
 :invalid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 75%;
 }
 :invalid ~:invalid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 50%;
 }
 
 :invalid ~:invalid ~:invalid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 25%;
 }
 
 :invalid ~:invalid ~:invalid ~:invalid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 0%;
 }

 div {
   padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
R1 <input type="radio" name="">
R2 <input type="radio" name="">
R3 <input type="radio" name="">
R4 <input type="radio" name="">
Name <input type="text" name="" required=required>
Last <input type="text" name="" required=required>
Address <input type="text" name="" required=required>
Age <input type="text" name="" required=required>
<div>
  <button>Radio</button>
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
```

### Update

Here is the explanation regarding the `:valid`:

Because the checkbox inputs exists and they don't have the `required` attribute - they are valid. So you actually have 4 `:valid` elements before the `button:nth-child(2)`, which mean you will have the background set to to `100% 100%`.
If you want - you can make sure that the `:valid` selector will be only for the regular text-fields: `input[type=text]:valid` and this will solve the problem (Another option is to set a class to these fields).

Check this update (based only your code, with the `:valid` selector):

```css
button {
   color: #FFF;
   border: none;
   background-color: transparent;
   transition: all 1s;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 20px 50px;   
   background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 100%);
   background-position: 100% 100%;
   background-size: 100% 0%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
  :checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 25%;
 }

 :checked ~:checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 50%;
 }
 
 :checked ~:checked ~:checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 75%;
 }
 
 :checked ~:checked ~:checked ~:checked ~ div > button:first-child {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
input[type=text]:valid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 25%;
 }
input[type=text]:valid ~input[type=text]:valid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 50%;
 }
 
 input[type=text]:valid ~input[type=text]:valid ~input[type=text]:valid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 75%;
 }
 
 input[type=text]:valid ~input[type=text]:valid ~input[type=text]:valid ~input[type=text]:valid ~ div > button:nth-child(2) {
   background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
 div {
   padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
R1 <input type="radio" name="">
R2 <input type="radio" name="">
R3 <input type="radio" name="">
R4 <input type="radio" name="">
Name <input type="text" name="" required=required>
Last <input type="text" name="" required=required>
Address <input type="text" name="" required=required>
Age <input type="text" name="" required=required>
<div>
  <button>Radio</button>
  <button>Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Will appreciate if you can also accept the answer. I will try to explain why the `:valid` isn't work...

Comment: You are smart dealer :)

Comment: You could always ask for explanation ;) haha

Comment: @DavidJorHpan, there you go :) (check the update part)